# No close button on dialog in Centos 7

Tags: java, linux, centos, swt, jface

My company product runs on Centos7, it has some problem when it displays somewhere(and it is OK on Windows).

And I had searched from the Internet, maybe it is much familiar with this **[one](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=75309)** but this question didn't have any answers.

And the dialog extends as Window---> Dialog(org.eclipse.jface.....)

Comment: The close button on the window border? The one provided by the window manager?

Comment: There is no any button on the dialog window border.I do not know why.....If the dialog pop up ,there is no way to close it ,except use the esc button on the keybord.

Comment: So you are talking about the close button that is normally provided by the window manager? Presumably that used to be there but is gone now? Or do you mean a close button *in* the window (that also used to be there but isn't anymore)?